# Check if mouse is inside the game window

Tags: .net, xna

I'm using XNA to visualize a 3D scene in a window (= not full-screen). The user can click and drag the mouse to move the camera:

```vb
Public Sub New()
    ...
    Me.IsMouseVisible = True
    Me.Window.AllowUserResizing = True
    ...
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Update(ByVal gameTime As Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime)
    Dim m = Mouse.GetState()

    ' Change camera position based on m
    ...
End Sub
```

This works. The problem is that this even works when the mouse is *not* inside the game window, which looks a bit strange (I move a mail in Outlook and the 3D scene in the other window starts turning).

I didn't find a `Mouse.IsInsideGameWindow()` property. Is there anything else that I can (easily) do to avoid this?

Comment: @Downvoter: Feedback to improve the question is always appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
bool IsMouseInsideWindow()
{
    MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();
    Point pos = new Point(ms.X, ms.Y);
    return GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Contains(pos);
}
```

Comment: You could even make this into an extension of the MouseState object like this: `bool IsInsideGameWindow(this MouseState state) { Point pos = new Point(state.X, state.Y); return GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Contains(pos); }`. Don't know how to translate to VB.NET though.

Comment: Thanks! Since XNA 3.1 doesn't have `Viewport.Bounds` yet, I've settled with `Return ms.X >= 0 AndAlso ms.Y >= 0 AndAlso ms.X <= GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width AndAlso ms.Y <= GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height`. Apparently, the mouse coordinates returned by MouseState are relative to the top-left corner of the window.

Comment: I believe that's XNA in general.